# Semantic roles "Location" or "Goal"?

Tags: semantics, semantic-roles

In this sentence: "We've just arrived at the airport." Is the semantic role of "the airport" Goal (because the airport is the destination where we moved to) or Location (because we are at the airport rn)?

Comment: It depends on how you define Goal and Location.

Comment: To me, "Location" designates where an entity is, while "Goal" designates where an entity moves to.